# OpenERP - how to add submenu in "More" button on form view

Tags: python, odoo

In Bill of Materials view I have "More" button/dropdown menu, please see the picture. I want to add a submenu to it, that will launch another, custom, form. How I can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all about assigning `key2` as `client_action_multi` or `client_print_multi` in your act_window.

Please refer to this post: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-add-submenu-to-more-button-on-form-view-17410